# In Lyx how do I set up a display formula over several lines

Tags: equations, lyx

In Lyx, when I have a long equation in display mode I would like to display it over several lines for readability.  But whenever I try to do that Lyx gives me an empty table.  Is there some tex command I can insert into my equation to force a line split?

Comment: You can use the split environment within the equation and make new lines with \\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot about this in Help>Math, Long Formulas. Use, for example, Insert>Math>Eqnarray and add additional rows by pressing Ctrl-Enter, or Edit>Math>Add Line. In some cases you'll need Insert>Math>AMS multiline, and similar. This wiki page has a nice summary of these environments https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics

Comment: please!  not `eqnarray`!  there must be some other possibilities like `align` or `gather`.

Comment: Sure there are. Insert>Math>AMS align/alignat/flalign/gather/multiline are all there. @Betty will have to choose what's right for her.

Comment: PhilipPirrip -- found a good solution in your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Insert -> Math-> AMS Multiline Environment

write your equation and click 'Ctrl+Enter' where you want to split 
Then Right click the equation and select number whole formula