# Using Lyx, How to I insert multiple line equations?

Tags: equations, lyx

In Lyx, I have the following Display Formula:

1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17 (1)

I want to split it into:

1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+

+11+12+13+14+15+16+17 (1)

I found this https://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/FormulaOnMultipleLines and [In Lyx how do I set up a display formula over several lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301318/in-lyx-how-do-i-set-up-a-display-formula-over-several-lines). but still cannot get multiline equations to work!

For example the answer by riddleculous:  "You can use the split environment within the equation and make new lines with \" - How can I make this work?

Comment: The `amsmath` environments usually used for such things (`split`, `aligned`, , `align` etc. are available in the Insert --> Math manu.

Comment: Do you know how to "insert" `\begin{multline} 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 \\ +11+12+13+14 +15+16+17 \end{multline}` into your lyx document?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Mico mentions, the `multline` environment is made for this type of thing.  Go to Insert --> Math, and choose *AMS multline environment*. You get what looks like a normal display math inset:

[image]

Type the first line, and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will get a new blue placeholder box on the next line:

[image]

Move the cursor into this field (hit <kbd>↓</kbd>), and type the next line:

[image]

You can repeat this if you want to. `multline` will place the first line flush left, the last line flush right, and all the lines in between centered.

Comment: Note that this won't work if you're already inside a Math environment like `align`. In that case, use `aligned` inside a cell of `align`.