# Outside of margin Equation

Tags: equations, lyx, margins

I am working with Lyx and am trying to fit an equation in my margin as it is getting out side of the margin as can be seen in the below image.

[image]

I have tried to use the multiline enviornment but it still did not work. I have also looked at different questions but were not helpful.

Can someone help please?

Below is a screen shot of how I am inputting the formula and what I have used in LYX.

[image]

Comment: You can use `align`,  load package `mathtools` , split the equation after the `=` sign and use `\MoveEqLeft` for the first line.

Comment: @Bernard - what do you mean by use `MoveEqLeft` because when I did it, the equation moved all to the left which is even worse now

Comment: It has to be used on a line by line basis, for those which need an emulated indent

Comment: Please at least provide the formula code and also the necessary starting `\documentclass` and ending `\end{document}`. Although your question is essentially about breaking equation into multiple lines, it is helpful that you provide source code to save others the typing.

Comment: I'm surprised that the `multline` environment didn't work.  But you said `multiline`; that's entirely different.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - That is a typo from my end which. The right one is `AMS multline Enviornment` in LYX which did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here two possibilities: one with the `aligned` environment, nested in `equation, ans using`\MoveEqLeft`from`mathtools`, the other uses`flalign`and an *adhoc* alignment point. Both use the medium-size fractions (`\mfrac`) from`nccmath`for the numerical fractions, as I think it looks better:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{off-margin}
\begin{aligned}
 \MoveEqLeft -\ell (\beta _{0},\boldsymbol{\beta }) + \lambda \|\boldsymbol{\beta }\|_{1} = \\
 & \biggl[-\frac{1}{n}\biggl(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (\beta _{0}x_{i0} + \mathbf{x}^T\boldsymbol{\beta })y_i-\log(1 + \exp(\beta _{0}x_{i0} + \mathbf{x}^T\boldsymbol{\beta }))\biggr)\biggr] \\
 \text{where} &\phantom{ + } \boldsymbol{\beta } = (\beta _{1},\dots, \beta _{p})^{T}\text{ and } x_{i0} = 1 \text{ for all }i.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Next, we need to show that the negative log-likelihood function is convex. By showing convexity it means that a local minimum exists which is the global minimum…

\begin{flalign}
  \label{off-margin1}
-\ell (\beta _{0},\boldsymbol{\beta }) & + \lambda \|\boldsymbol{\beta }\|_{1} = \notag \\
 &\phantom{ + } \biggl[-\mfrac{1}{n}\biggl(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (\beta _{0}x_{i0} + \mathbf{x}^T\boldsymbol{\beta })y_i-\log(1 + \exp(\beta _{0}x_{i0} + \mathbf{x}^T\boldsymbol{\beta }))\biggr)\biggr] \\%
 \text{where} &\phantom{ + } \boldsymbol{\beta } = (\beta _{1},\dots, \beta _{p})^{T}\text{ and } x_{i0} = 1 \text{ for all }i. \notag
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to thank you for the above however this is still not working. My `document class` is `book (standard class)`. I don't know if this impacts the whole thing. I will add in my question some screen shots of how the lyx write is being shown

Comment: used this link: and seems it is working
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365948/using-lyx-how-to-i-insert-multiple-line-equations

Comment: What does ‘not working’ mean, exactly? Does the result still overflow in the margin? Whether it is the book or the article class has no importance here. The only problem I can imagine would come from your real margins, which I don't know.

Comment: Basically what was happening the formula was still going outside my margins. But I have sorted it usng the `AMS Multline Equation`

Comment: I agree `multline` should work, but I don't understand why an aligned solution doesn't.